# How to set the length of permutations of a given string?

Tags: c#, permutation

I have the code which prints all possible permutations of a given string. How to set the length of one permutation? For example if the lenght is 2 then output should contains 6 possible permutations from ABCD.

```
class GFG 
{ 
    /** 
    * permutation function 
    * @param str string to 
    calculate permutation for 
    * @param l starting index 
    * @param r end index 
    */
    private static void permute(String str, 
                                int l, int r) 
    { 
        if (l == r) 
            Console.WriteLine(str); 
        else
        { 
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) 
            { 
                str = swap(str, l, i); 
                permute(str, l + 1, r); 
                str = swap(str, l, i); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
    * Swap Characters at position 
    * @param a string value 
    * @param i position 1 
    * @param j position 2 
    * @return swapped string 
    */
    public static String swap(String a, 
                            int i, int j) 
    { 
        char temp; 
        char[] charArray = a.ToCharArray(); 
        temp = charArray[i] ; 
        charArray[i] = charArray[j]; 
        charArray[j] = temp; 
        string s = new string(charArray); 
        return s; 
    } 

// Driver Code 
public static void Main() 
{ 
    String str = "ABCD"; 
    int n = str.Length; 
    permute(str, 0, n-1); 
} 
}
```

Comment: If the length is 2 and there are 4 characters, then there are 12 potential outputs.

Comment: If the length of the output is different from the input, it's not a permutation. From the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation): "In mathematics, a permutation of a set is, loosely speaking, an arrangement of its members into a sequence or linear order, or if the set is already ordered, a rearrangement of its elements." You are looking for a way to select all subsets of a certain size from a set.

Comment: @Martin Sorry. I confused with another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally missed that this was using a variable number of number arrangements (i.e. 5 source characters to all of the 2 character strings that could be generated).  I've since revised this to show extra detail.

This is probably a mathematic rather than programming questions.

In order to calculate the number of permutations for source characters `c` with the maximum output length `l`, use the following:

```
result = c! / (c - l)!
```

In the case of your example of 4 characters and a maximum of 2-character output, this gives:

```
result = 4! / (4 - 2)!
       = 4! / 2!
       = 24 / 2
       = 12
```

To calculate this in C# is not difficult - calculate the factorial (`!`) of `c` and the difference between `c` and `l` and divide the first by the second:

Using the handy function below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the factorial of the specified number.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="n">An int indicating the number to get the factorial of.</param>
/// <returns>An int indicating the factorial.</returns>
private static int getFactorial(int n)
{
    int returnValue = 1;

    while (n > 1)
        returnValue *= n--;

    return returnValue;
}
```

This can be done using:

```
int result = getFactorial(4) / getFactorial(4 - 2);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
12
```

This can also be placed into its own function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the factorial of n to length l.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="n">An int indicating the number of items in the set.</param>
/// <param name="l">An int indicating the length of the output.</param>
/// <returns>An int indicating the result.</returns>
private static int getFactorial(int n, int l)
{
    if (l > n) throw new ArgumentException("The legnth of the output may not be larger than the number of items", nameof(l));
    return getFactorial(n) / getFactorial(n - l);
}
```

Used as such:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The factorial of 4 by 2 is {getFactorial(4, 2)}");
Console.WriteLine($"The factorial of 5 by 3 is {getFactorial(5, 3)}");
Console.WriteLine($"The factorial of 6 by 2 is {getFactorial(6, 2)}");
```

Outputs:

```
The factorial of 4 by 2 is 12
The factorial of 5 by 3 is 60
The factorial of 6 by 2 is 30
```

**Note:** Using an `int` may not be the best choice.  At low numbers it works well but as soon as you have a 13-character string (`13!`) it will overflow and give an invalid result. `13! = 6,227,020,800` which is clearly bigger than an int32 in C#.